# Spring boot JSON parse error : Cannot deserialize value

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, react-hooks

I'm having trouble submitting the form. In the RoominfoController, I made changes to make it accept arrays, but the problem still persists..

---

`` Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.pgfinder.models.RoomInfo` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.example.pgfinder.models.RoomInfo` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]] ``

This is the form through which I am sending data.

1. [RoomInfo.js file](https://github.com/PranjalbaZala/Online-PGFinder-Management/blob/main/Front-end/src/components/RoomInfo.js)
2. [RoomInfoController.java](https://github.com/PranjalbaZala/Online-PGFinder-Management/blob/main/Back-end/src/main/java/com/example/pgfinder/controller/RoomInfoController.java)
3. [Model Class:RoomInfo.java](https://github.com/PranjalbaZala/Online-PGFinder-Management/blob/main/Back-end/src/main/java/com/example/pgfinder/models/RoomInfo.java)
4. [RoomInfoService.js](https://github.com/PranjalbaZala/Online-PGFinder-Management/blob/main/Front-end/src/services/RoomInfoService.js) (Here I have specified the method createRoomInfo)

---

I took reference of some similar answers on this site but it didn't work for me. The error is still being displayed in eclipse console when trying to enter values.

---

I am trying to send the roominfos array through this form.

```
{
    "pg_name": "Devanshi Hostel",
    "pg_address": "Vastrapur behind Gurudwara",
    "phone_no": "9912343234",
    "notice_period": 21,
    "gender": "Girls",
    "country": "India",
    "state": "Gujarat",
    "city": "Dwarka",
    "deposit_amt": 5000,
    "food_avail": "Yes",
    "wifi_avail": "No",
    "request_status": "Pending",
    "roominfos": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "shared_no": 1,
            "no_of_rooms": 1,
            "total_capacity": 1,
            "vacancy": 1,
            "rent_per_month": 1000
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "shared_no": 3,
            "no_of_rooms": 1,
            "total_capacity": 3,
            "vacancy": 2,
            "rent_per_month": 1000
        }
    ],
    "id": 18
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add to the question the json your JS code sends to backend? Also it's important for model class to have default constructor. As an addition - usually it's a bad practice to use entities as DTO objects.

Comment: Noted. Will add the default constructor as well as will keep model and DTO classes different. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For me adding default constructor to model class solved the issue.
and one more thing - please use DTO for such operations , use of entity is not a good practise.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes, I will create a DTO package and DTO files for it.